# Zoom on tree layout preserve root node location

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I am quite new to d3 and am having trouble with zooming and dragging on a tree layout.

**EDIT: Updated JSFiddle with information from comments**

I have created a sample, JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d644L/2/).

My issue is in the zoom function:

```
function zoom() {
        var scale = d3.event.scale,
            translation = d3.event.translate,
            tbound = -height * scale * 100,
            bbound = height * scale,
            lbound = (-width + margin.right) * scale,
            rbound = (width - margin.bottom) * scale;
        console.log("pre min/max" + translation);
        // limit translation to thresholds
        translation = [
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)];
        console.log("scale" + scale);
        console.log("translation" + translation);
        d3.select("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" +
            " scale(" + scale + ")");
    }
```

If you expand and collapse nodes and then try to drag, the root node always goes back to the top left corner.  I added some logging that shows that the value of `translation` in this case is -1,-1

Is there a way I can preserve the current root node position?

Comment: There are a number of questions on this, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405638/d3-js-zooming-and-panning-a-collapsible-tree-diagram) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785896/how-can-i-add-zooming-to-the-d3-collapsible-tree-example). Could you have a look if these solve your problem please?

Comment: Thanks. I actually used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543127/d3-collapse-tree-zoom-and-pan-jumpiness-after-clicking-a-node?rq=1) and moved the zoom function outside the update, but the very first time I move the tree, I am still having the issue.  Any idea why? (updated JSFiddle in question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `g` element you're translating with the zoom behaviour is initialised with a non-zero translation. The zoom behaviour is not aware of this, resulting in the "jump" you see. To fix, initialise the zoom behaviour with that translation.

```
var zb = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5, 5]).on("zoom", function () {
        zoom();
    });
zb.translate([margin.left, margin.top]);
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d644L/3/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Makes perfect sense.